# Remove gray CSS overlay for images in Community

Tags: community, css, lightning-community, community-builder

CSS Ninjas,

I need some help regarding CSS with Communities. It appears that the default Napili template adds a gray background overlay on images such as the Banner image and the Featured Topic pictures that looks like this:

[image]

Is this possible to remove with the custom CSS branding editor in the Builder? I did some research and tried to use this code with no luck:

`.class {
    background-color: transparent;
}`

What am I doing incorrect here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

refer the appropriate class under the template Branding

```
.forceCommunityOmniBox .no-assigned-image .default-bg-overlay {
    background: transparent;
}
```

[image]